# whenever i am trying to open firefox, it shows a massage " firefox is already open but not responding"

Tags: 12.04, firefox, crash

I am trying to open Firefox browser in my system. But every time it is showing  message that "firefox is already open but not responding. Please restart the system". Even after restarting the system it showing the same message, when i again try to open it.

Comment: There might be a crashed firefox instance stuck. What is the output of `ps aus | grep -i firefox` in the Terminal?

Comment: Try `killall firefox-bin` on a terminal with `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

Check the Firefox profile directory `.mozilla/firefox/<profile>` in your home directory and see if there is a file named `.parentlock`. Removing it should allow you to open Firefox again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem and,

```
killall firefox
```

fixed it.

But what's strange here is that you say even reboot didn't fix that!

Answer (score -1):

Firefox has a memory leak. Run htop and kill the process.